# The name timeLabel does not exist in current context

Tags: asp.net

I am using VS 2015 and my coding language is C#. I am trying to create a simple web site in aspx that produces the server time and allows you to change the colors of the clock. Anyways, I have this error that says "The name timeLabel does not exist in the current context" Here is my code so far.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebTime.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.WebTime" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Server Time</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       .timeStyle {
          color: red;
          font-size: xx-large;
          background-color: blanchedalmond;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
       <h2>
          Current time on the Web server:</h2>
       <p>
          <span id="timeLabel" runat="server" class="timeStyle" >02:55:28</span>
       </p>
           <p>
          New background color:
          <asp:DropDownList ID="backColorDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
             <asp:ListItem>Black</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>White</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Blue</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Red</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Green</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Purple</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Yellow</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
       </p>
       <p>
          New foreground color:
          <asp:DropDownList ID="foreColorDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
             <asp:ListItem>Yellow</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Black</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>White</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Blue</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Red</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Green</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Purple</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
       </p>
       <p>
          New font size:
          <asp:DropDownList ID="fontSizeDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
             <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
       </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CodeBehind file too:

```
// Code-behind file for a page that displays the current time
// and updates properties based on user input.
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Web
{
    public partial class WebTime : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        // initializes the contents of the page
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // display the server's current time in timeLabel
            timeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        } // end method Page_Init

        // when loading due to a postback, Page_Load modifies 
        // the Label's properties based on user input
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // if this is a postback, process user input
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                // retrieve the values submitted by the user
                string backColor = backColorDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
                string foreColor = foreColorDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
                int fontSize =
                   Convert.ToInt32(fontSizeDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text);

                // modify timeLabel based on the user's selections
                timeLabel.BackColor = Color.FromName(backColor);
                timeLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromName(foreColor);
                timeLabel.Font.Size = fontSize;
            } // end if
        }  
    }       
}
```

The errors happen in my CodeBehind file.

"timeLabel", "backColorDropDownList", "foreColorDropDownList", and "fontSizeDropDownList" have the errors.

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate the asp controls inside a form element:

```html
...
<body>
  <form runat="server">
    <div> 
       <h2>
          Current time on the Web server:</h2>
       <p>
          <span id="timeLabel" runat="server" class="timeStyle" >02:55:28</span>
       </p>
           <p>
          New background color:
          <asp:DropDownList ID="backColorDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
             <asp:ListItem>Black</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>White</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Blue</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Red</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Green</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Purple</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Yellow</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
       </p>
       <p>
          New foreground color:
          <asp:DropDownList ID="foreColorDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
             <asp:ListItem>Yellow</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Black</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>White</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Blue</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Red</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Green</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Purple</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
       </p>
       <p>
          New font size:
          <asp:DropDownList ID="fontSizeDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
             <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
       </p>
    </div>

 </form>
</body>
...
```

Comment: You should also use the <asp:label> element instead of <span>. It is easier to handle labels on the code behind.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I did as you suggested and i still have the same errors.

Comment: It works well here. Did you replace the <span> with the <label> too?

Comment: Change your span to have `runat="server"` in it if you still have that, or use an <asp:Label /> instead. The code-behind has no knowledge of anything other than server controls.

Comment: dang, yea i did that as well. You think it has anything to do with me using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: The VS 2015 shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: I checked the code again and it seems ok to me.
As it is such a simple code, I suggest you to start over. Insert a new webform to your project and re-write the code.
If the error persists, then maybe it is the Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Okay, yea. ill start there. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you getting an error on something as simple as this.Still just paste the below code to display the current time and see

```
  <h2>Current time on the Web server:</h2>
   <p>
      <asp:Label ID="timeLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </p>
```

and let me know what error message that comes up